# Saving NSTimer to NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, nstimer

I'm doing a simple game for the iPhone and now that is finished, I'd like to add a timer. I managed to implement the timer, but now I want to pause it when an incoming SMS or Phone Call minimize the application.
I thought that I should put the timer in the app delegate and, when applicationWillResignActive/applicationDidBecomeActive will be called, save/restore the timer object with NSUserDefaults, but I see that I can only save "raw" data, not entire objects.
How can i manage this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store the elapsed time in a variable (I wouldn't use NSUserDefaults) and then create a new timer with the elapsed time subtracted.

See this question for some more info: [How can I programmatically pause an NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347219/how-can-i-programmatically-pause-an-nstimer)

Comment: Maybe I coded wrong, but basically I don't need the state itself of the timer but to launch the selector in the subview to refresh a UILabel...

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. I thought you wanted to 'pauze' a NSTimer on `applicationWillResignActive` and 'start' it again on `applicationDidBecomeActive`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but I don't need the "value" itself, just the "repetitions". Anyway I guess I've solved the matter in another way.