# Pause NSTimer on home-button-press and start them again once the app is in foreground

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nstimer

I've been searching for a solution to pause my SpriteKit game when the user "tabs down" the game. So far I found a solution where you use `SKAction`'s instead of `NSTimer`'s, this works as long as the time between actions stays the same. However, my `NSTimer`'s changes in speed. So I need to find another solution.

I have a bunch of `NSTimer`'s located in `GameScene -> didMoveToView`

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnBullets"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnMeteors"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval, target: self, selector: Selector("onTimer:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Now, how would I simply pause them when the app enters background?

EDIT: Added my timeInterval increase-speed-function

```
func onTimer(timer: NSTimer) {
    var goodTimes = time / 20

    if (goodTimes > 1.8){
        goodTimes = 1.8
    }

    timer.fireDate = timer.fireDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(timeInterval - goodTimes)

    self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(SpawnRocks), SKAction.waitForDuration(goodTimes / 2), SKAction.runBlock(SpawnPowerUp)]))
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my `NSTimer` changes in speed?"

Comment: Sorry, i added my function for clarification.

Also, the "time" variable increases by 1 every second (in another function)

Comment: I expect [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347219/how-can-i-programmatically-pause-an-nstimer) will get you most of the way there.

Comment: You can implement the same functionality with a `waitForDuration` and `runAction` SKAction sequence, where the `runAction` block calls `onTimer`. The difference is you will need to create/run a new action sequence (wait/runAction) each time `onTimer` is called.

Comment: @TwoStraws This seems to be Objective-C right? I would greatly appreciate an example in swift :) @ 0x141E Do you think this guide is up to date and working using SKActions? http://blog.adambardon.com/how-to-pause-spritekit-game-in-swift/ (Also including for future readers having the same problem)

Comment: @Glutch: That blog post looks perfect to me.

Comment: @TwoStraws Awesome. Is the SKAction the best way to go efficiency-wise? It seems hard on the fps to recreate the runAction every time, maybe this is a dumb question. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I suspect an `SKAction` timer approach will have little or no effect on FSP compared to an `NSTimer` implementation. Using an `SKAction` timer will 1) pause/resume appropriately when you pause/resume the scene or view, 2) automatically pause/resume when you press the home button and relaunch your app, and 3) automatically stop and release memory when you transition to a new scene. Alternatively, you will need to manually invalidate each `NSTimer` when you transition to a new game level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pausing of `NSTimer` is not a native feature in objective-c or swift. To combat this,  you need to create an extension,  which I happen to have created and will share for you.  This will work for both OS X and iOS

```
import Foundation
import ObjectiveC

#if os(iOS)
    import UIKit
#else
    import AppKit
#endif


private var pauseStartKey:UInt8 = 0;
private var previousFireDateKey:UInt8 = 0;

extension NSTimer
{
    private var pauseStart: NSDate!{
        get{
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &pauseStartKey) as? NSDate;

        }
        set(newValue)
        {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &pauseStartKey,newValue,objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
        }
    }

    private var previousFireDate: NSDate!{
        get{
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &previousFireDateKey) as? NSDate;

        }
        set(newValue)
        {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &previousFireDateKey,newValue,objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
        }
    }


    func pause()
    {
        pauseStart = NSDate();
        previousFireDate = self.fireDate;
        self.fireDate = NSDate.distantFuture() ;
    }

    func resume()
    {
        if(pauseStart != nil)
        {
            let pauseTime = -1 * pauseStart.timeIntervalSinceNow;
            let date = NSDate(timeInterval:pauseTime, sinceDate:previousFireDate );
            self.fireDate = date;
        }

    }
}
```

Then when you need to use it, simply call `timer.pause()` and `timer.resume()`  You of course have to keep track of your timers in your gamescene object to do this,  so make sure that `timer` is a variable accessible for the entire class, and when making your timer, you do `timer = NSTimer.schedule...`

At the beginning of your class:

```
var spawnBulletsTimer : NSTimer?;
var spawnMeteorsTimer : NSTimer?;
var onTimer: NSTimer?;
```

When creating the timers:

```
spawnBulletsTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target:     self, selector: Selector("SpawnBullets"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

spawnMeteorsTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnMeteors"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

onTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval, target: self, selector: Selector("onTimer:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Then when you need to pause:

```
onTimer?.pause() 
spawnBulletsTimer?.pause()
spawnMeteorTimer?.pause()
```

Then when you need to resume:

```
onTimer?.resume() 
spawnBulletsTimer?.resume()
spawnMeteorTimer?.resume()
```

Comment: Hello (again) Knight0fDragon! :) I'm struggling a tiny bit with this. "make sure that timer is a variable accessible for the entire class". So i put timer inside "class GameScene: SKScene". But what should it be equal to? I tried timer = NSTimer(). But that didn't seem to be the right choice.

Comment: I have added everything, no errors showing up, i see nothing strange except xcode forcing me to put either "!" or "?" at onTimer"?".pause(), spawnBulletsTimer"?".pause(). It doesn't seem to work though, the when i re-open the game theres a lot of meteors spawning. Can i upload my code somewhere and you take a look?

Comment: the ? is what you want,  sorry I write in many languages and I always leave out the optional symbols.   I would assume a lot of meteors happen,  10 a second in fact,if you are getting more than this,  then you are creating more timers than you should be

Comment: Thanks for the update, however, it doesn't work. It still spawns a bunch of meteors when the game returns to foreground. I see no errors or such, as i said in my earlier comment. The 0.1 timer was just an example, in reality its much less frequent :') Edit for clarification. My meteors spawns with my onTimer function (SpawnRocks). They spawn approx 1 each second. When i enter background, and re-enters foreground after a while, theres a huge amount of Meteors(Rocks) in my game, so the timers did in fact not stop running

Comment: check in with me in 2 hours,  I will be able to look at your code then

Comment: Should the code be added to AppDelegate.swift or GameScene.swift? I found some interesting functions in AppDelegate.swift and moved the code there. Doesnt seem to work though :D

Comment: What code? The extension?  Make it its own swift file

Comment: Okey, haha! It all works now. Huge thanks, i appreciate your patience

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @KnightOfDragon code, here's a more modern swift version:

```
import Foundation

private var pauseStartKey:UInt8 = 0;
private var previousFireDateKey:UInt8 = 0;

extension Timer{
    
    private var pauseStart: Date!{
        
        get{
            
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &pauseStartKey) as? Date
        }
        
        set(newValue){
            
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &pauseStartKey,newValue,objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }

    private var previousFireDate: Date! {
        
        get{
            
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &previousFireDateKey) as? Date
        }
        
        set(newValue){
            
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &previousFireDateKey,newValue,objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }


    func pause() {
        
        pauseStart = Date()
        previousFireDate = fireDate
        fireDate = Date.distantFuture
    }

    func resume() {
        
        if pauseStart != nil {
            
            let pauseTime = -1 * pauseStart.timeIntervalSinceNow;
            let date = Date(timeInterval: pauseTime, since: previousFireDate)
            fireDate = date;
        }
    }
}
```